# Acronym Package: italicize first occurrence of a term

Tags: acronyms

Is it possible to use the `acronym` package to italicize the first occurrence of a term as with the `acro` package?

Comment: You should be able to redefine `\acffont` and `\acfsfont` (macros taking as argument the text to typeset). It will affect uses of `\acf` and `\acf*`. Judging from the definition of `\@ac`, I don't think you can modify the formatting for first use without affecting the output of `\acf` or `\acf*`.

Comment: But if it only affects the uses of `\acf` and `\acf*` then what is the point? I could just use `\acfi`. What I want is for the first expanded use of a term (when using `\ac`) to be italicized so that I don't have to do it manually.

Comment: I did not write that this would only affect the uses of `\acf` and `\acf*`.

Comment: Ah thanks! I will try it then.